# Wine: using webcam with Cisco Jabber Video client

Tags: wine, gstreamer, cisco

I'm trying to use Cisco Jabber Video client (https://www.ciscojabbervideo.com/home) with Wine but I'm unable to get the webcam to work.

Steps that I have completed this far:

1. Register an account for Cisco Jabber Video (required to get the download link for the application).
2. Install Cisco Jabber Video Client.
3. Run Cisco Jabber Video Client. This part was problematic until I found out that this application expects to find a copy of `ksuser.dll` int the system. I located a copy of said DLL from the dlldump.com and put it in `~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32` and everything else but video from webcam seems to work.

I'm able to successfully use the webcam without wine. The webcam already works with Skype, Cheese Webcam Viewer, `guvcview`, `luvcview` and Flash plugin (both Firefox and Google Chrome). Still the Cisco Jabber Video client running on wine claims that I have no USB webcam installed in the system.

I also tried to add `devenum` override and deleted `HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/ActiveMovie` with `regedit` as suggested by http://wiki.winehq.org/MSN_Messenger_webcam_support

**Can you suggest anything else to get the camera to work?** (The reason I even need this stuff is I would need to connect to Cisco TelePresence SX20 hardware on the remote site and it seems that Ekiga is not compatible with that. Ekiga is never able to establish a connection with that thing.)

**Update:**
I forgot to mention the hardware I'm using:

```
Bus 003 Device 064: ID 045e:075d Microsoft Corp. LifeCam Cinema
```

Software:

```
Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS 64-bit (precise with all the updates)
Wine 1.7.18-0ubuntu1 from ubuntu-wine PPA
```

Comment: Just in case someone has the same problem as me, I had to set Wine to Windows 7 mode with `winecfg` and I had to copy `ksuser.dll` to `~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system`. By the way, if you have made any breakthrough with the camera issue (mine doesn't work either) please let us know.
EDIT: seeing [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-use-usb-devices-a-webcam-in-this-case-in-wine-1-3-16-a-873968/) and [this](http://wiki.winehq.org/USB) (see bold text), I think using webcam is not possible right now.

Comment: I still haven't been able to get the webcam working with Cisco Jabber Video running with wine 1.7.18.

Answer (score 0):

A large number of cameras have been tested with several versions of Cisco Jabber Video for TelePresence. While Jabber Video should work with all USB cameras, the cameras that the Jabber Video team are using on a regular basis and are guaranteed to perform well are:

```
Cisco TelePresence PrecisionHD USB Camera (recommended for business-quality HD video)
Apple iSight cameras
Cisco VT Camera III
Creative Live! Cam Socialize HD 1080
Lenovo Thinkpad cameras
Logitech HD Pro Webcam C910
Logitech HD Webcam C310
Logitech QuickCam Pro
Logitech QuickCam Pro 9000
Microsoft LifeCam Studio
Microsoft LifeCam HD-6000
```

Cameras that support HD 1080

```
Logitech HD Pro Webcam C910
Microsoft LifeCam Studio
Creative Live! Cam Socialize HD 1080
HP Webcam HD-4110
```

Comment: I have Microsoft LifeCam Cinema (the hardware is roughly between Lifecam Studio and Lifecam HD-5000). I guess the list of supported cameras is only for native Windows installs, right?

Comment: Could you add a reference link for this information? i.e. where did you get this list.

Comment: Doing a search for the first sentence, I think this came from [here](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/telepresence/endpoint/articles/cisco_telepresence_movi_tested_cameras_kb_377.html).